# Can we create sprite sheet from a svg sequence?

Tags: svg, sprite, sprite-sheet

Adobe animate can convert the animation into svg sequence, but, for some reason, it only can generate png spritesheet. Not only animate, but all the sprite sheet generators i found(like texture packer and other) can only generate png and other bitmap format sprite sheet. Is there a way i can merge this svgs into spritesheet?

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=keywords%3Asprite%20svg

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65516030/i-cant-make-css-svg-animation-emoji-similar-to-pinterest-reactions/65522497#65522497