# I Can't make css svg animation emoji similar to Pinterest reactions

Tags: css, svg, css-animations

I can't make a CSS animation with my SVG sprite similar to Pinterest.
The sprite is 90 frames, but I can't get it to work

Pinterest Reactions Emojis
[image: Pinterest Reactions Emojis]

[View Pinterest Sprite 90 frames in Svg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ILB9G.png)

My code:

```css
.emoji{
  width: 110px;
  height: 110px;
  background-image : url(https://s.pinimg.com/webapp/style/images/wow-0a7ea725.svg);
  animation: moveX 1s steps(90) infinite;
}

@keyframes moveX{
  from{background-position-x:0px;}
  to{background-position-x:-500px;}
}
```

```html
<div class="emoji"></div>
```

My JSFiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/u81xkcon/

Comment: The only problem with your code was, that you did not set the width of the image correctly... if you instead went with `to{background-position-x:-100%;}` it would have worked like a charm;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you go

```css
.emoji {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 110px;
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  background-image: url(https://s.pinimg.com/webapp/style/images/wow-0a7ea725.svg);
  background-size: auto 100%;
  animation: moveX 1s steps(90) infinite;
}

@keyframes moveX {
  to {
    background-position: right; /* you only need to move to right */
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="emoji"></div>
<div class="emoji" style="width:50px"></div>
```

Comment: Excellent friend, thank you.

but I have a question ... why the animation vibrates in axis X?

Comment: @DavidPumaRios either the sprites aren't perfectly aligned or maybe a browser rendring issue

Comment: @DavidPumaRios I have update the code to get rid of it. Use 100% in the Y axis to avoid any room for jumping

Comment: what's the `::before` for? I don't see any use in that... otherwise, great answer!

Comment: @Christoph to keep the square ratio, notice how I used two div with different width and I never specified the height because the pseudo element will do it.

Comment: I'd rather specify the height attribute than put unnecessarily complicated code in there... ;-)

Comment: @Christoph it's not unecessary. Why specifying two attributes when you can only specify one? and what if you don't know the ratio of the icon? it can be square, 3:2, 16:9, 4:3, etc .. you will waste your time finding the correct value. Only set the width and the height is calculated automatically. There is nothing complex in the code, it's a known trick

Comment: Doesn't matter, you're setting the aspect ratio in the pseudo element, so you're locked into the square ratio again. If the image ratio changes, you have to adjust the padding of the pseudo element. I'd rather go with `height:calc(var(--image-width) * var(--aspect-ratio));`. And you would have to adjust it manually anyways because you can't read the intrinsic image properties with CSS.

Comment: @Christoph I am talking from a user perspective. I (the developer) know the ratio and I set it in the CSS. A user that will use the emoji to insert it in his code doesn't need to know the ratio of all the emoji**s** I designed, he simply need to specify one size and not try to find the ratio of each one. The example above is very simplified and is irrelevant, I considered a scalable solution considering many emojis and why not a whole library of emojis

Comment: Did not consider a c&p scenario, but fair point! ;-)

Comment: Been playing with this, is it possible to do **without** stuffing the SVG in a background image?

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman like this: https://jsfiddle.net/1vyz5thd/1/ ?

Comment: YES! (I was doing CSS wrong) Do you know if there are any sites\libraries combining SVG with template-literals?? like I show below... been extending that idea over the past days; is fun, considering Flash died last month. I searched and searched, but the icon sprite answers are plenty

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman not really, I am not very experiend when it comes to SVG

Answer (score 1):

If you take Temani his great answer, add a modern W3C standard Web Component that uses *Template Literal* parsing to **create the SVG sprite *Client Side*** in a shadowDOM

(*and do some better animation calculations in the* `<template>`)

You save downloading a **65KB** SVG file, and get:

```html
<svg-spriter w=100 h=100 s=40 width="130px">
  <template>
    <g id="sprite${n}_${s}" transform="translate(${n*w})">
      <rect x='5' y='5' width='90' height='90' rx='20' fill='#ffad65'></rect>
      <circle cx='30' cy='30' r='${12+(n<10?-n:n)*.1}'></circle>
      <circle cx='80' cy='30' r='${12+(n<10?n:-n)*.1}'></circle>
      <ellipse cx='60' cy='70' rx="${10+(n<20?n*0.5:((20-n)*-0.5))}" ry="5"></ellipse>
    </g>
  </template>
</svg-spriter>
<script>
  customElements.define("svg-spriter", class extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() { super().attachShadow({mode: "open"}) }
    connectedCallback() {
      const parsed = (template, vars = {}) => new Function('vars', [
        'let f = ( ' + Object.keys(vars).join(', ') + ' ) =>',
        '`' + template + '`','return f(...Object.values(vars))'
      ].join('\n'))(vars);
      setTimeout(() => { // wait till <template> is parsed by the Browser
        let attr = (x) => this.getAttribute(x);
        let [w, h, s] = ["w", "h", "s"].map(a => ~~attr(a));
        let width = attr("width");
        let frame = this.querySelector("template").innerHTML;
        let svg =
          (`data:image/svg+xml,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 ${s*w} ${h}'>` +
            Array(s).fill().map((s, n) => parsed(frame, {n,w,h,s})).join("") + "</svg>").replace(/#/g, "%23").replace(/\n/g, "").replace(/</g, "%3C").replace(/>/g, "%3E").replaceAll('"', "'");
        let html = `<style>div{width:${width};display:inline-flex;background-image: url("${svg}");background-size: auto ${width};animation:moveX 1s steps(${s-1}) infinite}div::before{content:"";padding-top:100%;}@keyframes moveX{to{background-position:right}}</style><div></div>`;
        html += `<br>Sprite as IMG:<br><img src="${svg}">`;
        this.shadowRoot.innerHTML = html;
      })
    }
  });
</script>
```